# find database size in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In phpmyadmin, it's able to see database disk usage. I was wondering if there's such thing in Oracle SQL developer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
select nvl(b.tablespace_name,
         nvl(a.tablespace_name,'UNKNOWN'))
         tablespace_name,
       kbytes_alloc kbytes,
       kbytes_alloc-nvl(kbytes_free,0) 
         size_alloc_bytes,
       round(((kbytes_alloc-nvl(kbytes_free,0))/
         kbytes_alloc)*200) used_chart,
       to_char(((kbytes_alloc-nvl(kbytes_free,0))/
         kbytes_alloc)*100,
         '999G999G999G999G999G999G990D00') ||'%' used,
       data_files
  from ( select sum(bytes)/1024/1024 Kbytes_free,
              max(bytes)/1024/1024 largest,
              tablespace_name
       from  sys.dba_free_space
       group by tablespace_name ) a,
     ( select sum(bytes)/1024/1024 Kbytes_alloc,
              tablespace_name, count(*) data_files
       from sys.dba_data_files
       group by tablespace_name )b
 where a.tablespace_name (+) = b.tablespace_name
```

[Source](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/application_express/html/3.0.1_and_xe.html)

Comment: I'm getting that "sys.dba_data_files" does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend the [Insider extension for SQL Developer (Raptor)](http://www.fourthelephant.com/sqldeveloper/download/).

Comment: I like this, but when ever trying to 'open insider view' the sqldeveloper hangs. how to resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: I had problems with some EA editions, but not with the latest SQL Developer version. I also have full privileges on a 10.2.0.4 database.

Comment: Maybe it was due to not have full privilege to database. But is there any error to be trace? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
select sum(bytes) Bytes,
round(sum(bytes)/power(1000,1)) KiloBytes,
round(sum(bytes)/power(1000,2)) MegaBytes,
round(sum(bytes)/power(1000,3)) GigaBytes,
round(sum(bytes)/power(1000,4)) TeraBytes,
round(sum(bytes)/power(1000,5)) PetaBytes,
round(sum(bytes)/power(1000,6)) ExaBytes,
round(sum(bytes)/power(1000,7)) ZettaBytes,
round(sum(bytes)/power(1000,8)) YottaBytes
from dba_data_files;
```

Ensure that you are logged in with sysdba privileges to run this script.

Answer (score 1):

If DB is monitored in Grid Control, then, in emrep database execute this query (History of DB size):

```
SELECT DECODE(m.metric_column, 'ALLOCATED_GB', 'ALLOCATED_GB', 'USED_GB', 'USED_GB') AS bb,
  m.rollup_timestamp AS rollup_timestamp,
  SUM(m.average) AS value
FROM mgmt$metric_daily m,
  mgmt$target_type t
WHERE t.target_guid=
  (SELECT target_guid FROM mgmt$target WHERE target_name='ORCL' /* Your DB name /
  )
AND (t.target_type ='rac_database'
OR (t.target_type ='oracle_database'
AND t.TYPE_QUALIFIER3 != 'RACINST'))
AND m.target_guid =t.target_guid
AND m.metric_guid =t.metric_guid
AND t.metric_name ='DATABASE_SIZE'
AND (t.metric_column ='ALLOCATED_GB'
OR t.metric_column ='USED_GB')
AND m.rollup_timestamp >= '01.01.2010' / Start date */
AND m.rollup_timestamp <= SYSDATE
AND DECODE(m.metric_column, 'ALLOCATED_GB', 'ALLOCATED_GB', 'USED_GB', 'USED_GB')='USED_GB'
GROUP BY DECODE(m.metric_column,'ALLOCATED_GB','ALLOCATED_GB','USED_GB','USED_GB'),
  m.rollup_timestamp
ORDER BY 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

> An oracle database consists of data files, redo log files, control
> files, temporary files.
>
> The size of the database actually means the
> total size of all these files.

```
select 
( select sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 data_size from dba_data_files ) +
( select nvl(sum(bytes),0)/1024/1024/1024 temp_size from dba_temp_files ) +
( select sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 redo_size from sys.v_$log ) +
( select sum(BLOCK_SIZE*FILE_SIZE_BLKS)/1024/1024/1024 controlfile_size from v$controlfile) "Size in GB"
from
dual
```

Source:
http://nimishgarg.blogspot.com/2010/05/oracle-total-size-of-database.html